# JabRef is renaming the citation keys

Tags: citations

I am using JabRef in my Mac Big Sur OS.

If I import from MathSciNet, it is overwriting the citation key.

At some place it is suggested to do the following:

- preferences -->  citation key generator --> uncheck overwrite existing keys
- put default pattern as "[CITATIONKEY]"

I am attaching the screenshot of the window.

[image]

But, when I try to import from arxiv, the citation key is missing completely.

I am attaching screenshot of the same.

[image]

How do I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Is there any other reference manager that has MathSciNet, arXiv, etc as extensions?

Comment: @Anyon arxiv entries already have keys. https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.08442 has citation key "biswas2021atiyah"

Comment: I see. I can reproduce that behavior now. Maybe it's worth trying one of the development builds. Seems like there's been some bug related to overwriting keys in v.5.3: https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/7420

Comment: @Anyon I do not fully understand what do you mean by "trying one of the development builds".. Kindly explain.. I have already seen the link you mentioned and learnt about [CITATIONKEY] from the same link.. Do you suggest any other reference manager that you think is suitable for similar purpose?

Comment: Yep, that was a bug which is already fixed in the latest dev version. You can get it here https://builds.jabref.org/main/
Remember to make a backup of your library before trying out the new version. (JabRef maintainer here)

Comment: @ChristophS I think this should be made as an answer..

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in [Version 5.3](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/7420)
Please try the latest [development version](https://builds.jabref.org/main/)

In Preferences -> Import : Uncheck "Generate a new key for imported entries"

Remember to make a backup of your library before trying out the new version.

Please note that there is also a JabRef support forum available here:
https://discourse.jabref.org/

(Disclaimer: JabRef maintainer here)

Comment: unfortunately, the bug is still there.. arxiv import is giving same error. It removed the citation key

Comment: can some one else please confirm if this new version is working for them? In the sense if it is not removing arxiv citation keys..

Comment: Generally: Preferences -> Import : Uncheck "Generate a  new key for imported entries".
If you use the web search panel: arXiv is a special case, JabRef query's the arXiv API which returns XML and parses that. That info does not contain a citationkey.

Comment: I am not sure if j understand this correctly.. Are you saying what ever jabref is doing it is not able to extract the citation key of arxiv.. If we ask jabref to not create new citation key, the arxiv thing remains empty..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes. you understood this correctly. No data from arxiv for this. (For reference: https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual#detailed_examples)

Comment: Ok. I am happy that I am not doing anything wrong. It just doesn't not happen in the way I want.. :D if [citationkey] is already fixing the problem of mathscinet renaming, what is the bug that is fixed in new version?

Comment: I forgot to say yesterday. Thank you so much for maintaining JabRef. :) :)